# Create ext4 partition on LVM

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, lvm, dropbox

I have a 2TB volume (RAID 5) on a Linux Mint .  I use Dropbox, which has stopped supporting any file type on Linux Mint 18.1 system. I would like to carve out a partition formatted in a manner Dropbox will like.  Is there a way to do this?

```
$ lsblk -f

NAME   FSTYPE  
sda  
sda1 xfs
sda2 LVM2_me
|- rhel-root xfs
|- rhel-swap swap [SWAP]
|- rhel-home xfs  /home
```

$ sudo vgs rhel
VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
rhel   1   3   0 wz--n- 1.91t 60.00m

Comment: I tried to help the formatting of the lsblk command, but perhaps you can copy & paste the actual output, then use the `{}` formatting button?

Comment: The output of `vgs rhel` would indicate if there's free space available to create a new LV & ext4 filesystem.

Comment: That looks like rhel not mint. Your question is unclear, you either need to create a new lv or downsize. How much free space do you have on the hard drive? See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LVM_CLI.html or similsr or perhaps use gparted

Comment: It's mint. It's a repurposed server. The raid array was set up under red hat.

Comment: Boot a live usb and make space either with g po artes or lvm as needed. Post if you have a problem